# How do I add paths to the Apache PATH variable?

Tags: php, apache, path

I've set in my custom.conf file in apache2 this:

```
SetEnv PATH $PATH:/opt/local/lib/mysql5/bin:/this-is-a-test
```

However it's not working. When I call:

```
$hey = shell_exec('env'." 2>&1"); var_dump($hey);
```

I get:

```
... PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/opt/local/bin
```

Can anyone help? I'm on Mac using Macports for my development environment.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That seems awfully strange to me that you are trying to set the PATH from within Apache. Instead, you should be setting the PATH for your system. There are several ways to do this in Mac OS X:

**User-specific**
For a single user, you can edit ~/.profile and add:

```
export PATH="$PATH":/opt/local/lib/mysql5/bin:/this-is-a-test
```

Or you can create/edit ~/.MacOSX/environment.plist and define the PATH that way.

**System-wide**
On newer versions of Mac OS X, there is a file named "/etc/paths" and there is a folder named "/etc/paths.d" that allow you to extend the default paths. Basically, you would create a file in "/etc/paths.d" that lists all the paths that you wish to add to the default paths. On versions of Mac OS X that do not support this (you can tell based on whether "/usr/libexec/path_helper" exists), one can edit the default paths for all users by placing the export statement above in /etc/profile.

Comment: Michael, thanks for responding. Both my .profile and .bash_login files have the specified paths, but PHP running on Apache doesn't recognize them. I just tried the /etc/paths.d/ option, but that didn't seem to work either, do I have to restart the machine for those to take affect? I restarted apache - nothing.

Comment: @TylerNZ, you need to close, then reopen the Terminal, and then restart Apache from within your environment in which those variables are defined.

Comment: tried that, still nothing ... I think something specific needs to be done for either apache or the root user, which apache is running as?

Comment: PHP shell_exec('env'); returns: 
DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/local/lib:
TERM=xterm-color
SHELL=/bin/bash
USER=root
SUDO_USER=joelt
SUDO_UID=501
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/launch-BAXRDR/Listeners
__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING=0x0:0:0
USERNAME=root
PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/opt/local/bin
_=/usr/bin/env
PWD=/Users/joelt/Sites
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
HOME=/Users/joelt
SUDO_COMMAND=/opt/local/apache2/bin/apachectl restart
SHLVL=2
LOGNAME=root
DISPLAY=/tmp/launch-dNcZy6/org.x

Comment: Hmmm, it seems that if you actually STOP and START apache, it fixed the issue. Simply RESTARTING did not do the trick. Weird.

Comment: Unfortunately, neither of those ways have worked for me. I'm running OS X Yosemite. I've tried either with user-specific or system-wide. Any ideas?

Answer (score 8):

for ubuntu server, in /etc/apache2/envvars,
for centos server, in /etc/sysconfig/httpd,
to add:

```
export PATH=<your php cli path>
```

and restart apache

Answer (score 0):

This question is old, but in case it helps others, if you are using *Windows* with `mod_fcgid` check if you have the `FcgidInitialEnv` set in your `httpd.conf`, and remove it to adopt the System PATH.

Answer (score 0):

**Macports Apache 2.4 install**

The only way I have found to get this to stick on a reboot is to edit the macports apache2.plist. Steps I took:

1.`sudo /opt/local/sbin/apachectl stop`

2.Edit plist: `/opt/local/etc/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.apache2/org.macports.apache2.plist`

And add:

```
<key>EnvironmentVariables</key>
<dict>
    <key>PATH</key>
    <string>/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:{add paths here}</string>
</dict>
```

3.`sudo port unload apache2`

4.`sudo port load apache2`

5.`sudo /opt/local/sbin/apachectl start`

Paths stick on a reboot. However the plist will probably be wiped on the next macports update I do.

EDIT : And this proved to be true. I upgraded to Mojave with an associated macports update, and had to re-apply the steps above