# $PATH environment variable for apache2 on mac

Tags: php, apache, macos, environment-variables

I am trying to get apache/php to recognize the path to my git. I have been researching and looking in all corners of the web and cannot find how to do this. Basically, no matter what I try, when I run `echo phpinfo();` the `Apache Environment` path does not change from `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`. And when I run `system('echo $PATH');` in PHP, it reads the same.

**System Information:**

- Mac OSX (Lion)
- Apache 2 (running as _www)
- PHP 5.3.6

Here is what I have tried editing so far:

- /etc/profile
- ~/.bash_profile
- ~/.profile
- /etc/path
- /etc/path.d/{NEW_FILE}

Nothing I have tried so far has changed the `$PATH` variable. Any ideas?

**SOLUTION**

So here is the final solution. I edited the

```
/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist
```

and added

```
<key>EnvironmentVariables</key>
<dict>
    <key>PATH</key>
    <string>/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/git/bin</string>
</dict>
```

Comment: [Have you tried turning it off and turning it on again](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nn2FB1P_Mn8)? (Seriously, though, have you restarted Apache since doing this?)

Comment: I was having problems running PHP ``exec()`` where the Apache shell had a different PATH than my Mac shell.  This solved my issue.

Comment: I had a similar problem with PHP using the Imagick module.  It wouldn't open a PDF file because (under the hood) Imagick uses Ghostscript's `gs` binary, which was on my system but not in Apache's $PATH.

Adding the above to the .plist file  and restarting apache solved it.

Comment: This worked for me. However, for some reason after I installed Sierra, my edits to org.apache.httpd.plist disappeared. I put them back in and restarted Apache to get it to work again.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can set the PATH environment variable in `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist`.

More in the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/launchd.plist.5.html).

Comment: Yeah, I read another question on here about this. I tried this too. And it didn't work. I got apache errors with this.

Comment: I just retried this and it worked. Not sure why it didn't before. But this seems to be the solution.

Comment: TBH, I don't know if it works the same on OS X, but on "normal" *nixes, a restart command to the apache process does not relaunch the process, hence it does not get an updated environment (what it does do is that it re-reads its conf file(s)). Maybe something similar is at play here.

Comment: BTW, I used `sudo apachectl restart` and it loads the new PATH settings from `org.apache.https.plist` just fine in this case.

Comment: Interesting - thanks for that info. I now wonder if was talking rubbish in the comment above...

Answer (score 4):

Did you update the PATH environment variable of user '_www'? Apache will read environment variables from the user runs itself. Or, it looks like you didn't restart apache after updating PATH environment variable.

- Check out the older discussion :

  - [How do I add paths to the Apache PATH variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2837697/how-do-i-add-paths-to-the-apache-path-variable)
  - [Setting environment variables in OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135688/setting-environment-variables-in-os-x)

And if you want to modify environment variable in PHP, getenv() and putenv() can be a better choice.

- getenv : http://php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php
- putenv : http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.putenv.php

  $path = getenv('PATH');
  putenv( "PATH=$path:/new_path_that_you_want_to_add" );

Comment: The `putenv()` is only a good solution if you modify your PHP code directly. It's not a good permanent solution if you have to add that to EVERY php script / app you write.

Comment: how to edit the PATH var for the _www users that doesnt exist in /users ?

Answer (score 3):

Important note for El Capitan (Apologies for the new answer - I don't have enough Rep to comment)

On OSX 10.11, the /System/Library folder is protected, so the files can't be edited.

You need to:

- Reboot into Recovery Mode (hold CMD + r after the startup sound)
- Once in recovery mode, go to Utilities > Terminal
- Run:
  `csrutil disable`
- Reboot back into OSX - you should now be able to change the files
- Once done, go back to recovery mode and run
  `csrutil enable`

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

I created this gist that helped me out from the information above:

https://gist.github.com/srayhunter/5208619

My problem was that PHP was not finding a program that we had installed under /usr/local/bin. Once we did the above it all worked and played nice on mac osx.

Answer (score 0):

for ubuntu server, in /etc/apache2/envvars,
for centos server, in /etc/sysconfig/httpd,
to add:

```
export PATH=<your php cli path>
```

and restart apache

Answer (score 0):

A similar problem to what I was having installing Derby. The way I solved it was by opening TextEdit. Select File > Open at this point press Shift + Command + . , this will allow you to view all the documents. Head to the user directory and search for a file called ".profile" . Open it and add the export VARIABLE= Value line for example:

export DERBY_HOME=/opt/local/share/java/derby/

Save the document and restart your terminal to see if the changes went into affect.