# OS X, Perl CGI environment

Tags: macos, perl, apache, cgi, environment-variables

On OS X Snow Leopard, I'm running the default Apache with perlbrew.

My PATH points to the perlbrew perl, so I expected `/usr/bin/env perl` to do the same, which it does from bash, but not via cgi scripts, which seem to use the system perl.

How can I have Apache use the perlbrew perl?

## Update

This question is answered on StackOverflow: [$PATH environment variable for apache2 on mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6833939/path-environment-variable-for-apache2-on-mac)

Interesting that PHP people consider it a valid question, but Perl people do not. It would have been helpful for the Perl people to have taken a few seconds to mention why they think the question does not relate to programming and matters as described by the FAQ.

Comment: I thought Apache CGI scripts' shebang lines related to software development as defined in the FAQ.

Answer (score 3):

When you run `/usr/bin/env perl`, it finds `perl` somewhere in your `$PATH` environment variable...which is set in one of your dotfiles (probably `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc`).

When Apache starts up, it typically gets started by `launchd` and does not receive any environment setup services from your shell initialization scripts.  You would need to modify the script that starts Apache to add the necessary directories to `$PATH`, or modify your CGI scripts to call the appropriate `perl` binary directly (by using `#!/path/to/my/perl` instead of `#!/usr/bin/env perl`).

Comment: This happens when apache is launched as `/usr/sbin/httpd -k start` from my dev shell. I can't use an explicit path, as the live machine and other devs setups are currently unknown quantities.

Comment: You could use SetEnv directives in your Apache configuration to set `$PATH`.

Comment: Could do, but I still want to know why this is happening.