# Set ENV PATH of php and ffmpeg to use it inside PHP scripts with CLI like shell_exec()

Tags: php, apache, path, ffmpeg, environment-variables

I would like to execute commands in a php script like this:

```
<?php
shell_exec(php myfile.php)
```

or

```
<?php
shell_exec(ffmpeg -i ...)
```

My problem, i think is that php and ffmpeg path are not properly configured in my apache environment because when i execute this:

```
<?php
var_dump(shell_exec("which php"));
var_dump(shell_exec("which ffmpeg"));
```

I get this answer:

```
string '/usr/bin/php' (length=13)
null
```

But in the terminal when i type:

```
which php
which ffmpeg
```

I get this answer:

```
/usr/local/opt/php55/bin/php
/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg
```

**So how can i set properly the php and ffmpeg environment path without always retype the complete path ?**

I am under Mac OsX 10.10 and i installed php and ffmpeg whith brew.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may put environment variables in the command just like in shell.

**Examples:**

```
shell_exec('PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/opt/php55/bin:$PATH which ffmpeg');
```

---

### *Alternative solution:*

In case you do not want to make the code dirty, you may configure your Apache environment variables as follow.

**Mac:**

Edit

```
/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist
```

and added

```
<key>EnvironmentVariables</key>
<dict>
    <key>PATH</key>
    <string>/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/opt/php55/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin</string>
</dict>
```

*(answer copied from [$PATH environment variable for apache2 on mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6833939/path-environment-variable-for-apache2-on-mac))*

**Other platforms:** (for your references)

https://serverfault.com/questions/151328/setting-apache2-path-environment-variable

Comment: Thanks you solved my problem ;) now when i do var_dump(shell_exec("which php")); i get the right path. But the var_dump(getenv('PATH')); give me again string '/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin' (length=29). Is it normal ?

Answer (score 0):

Add **ffmpeg** to your **PATH** environment variable, restart **Apache** server and retry

Comment: I already added ffmpeg and php in my environment variable in my .bash_profile like this : export PATH="$(brew --prefix homebrew/php/php55)/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH". So this is why i have access in my terminal to the right path when i type which php or which ffmpeg but this not spread to my apache server

Comment: have you restarted your apache after that ?

Comment: Yes i did but nothing change

Comment: please, `var_dump(getenv('PATH'));`

Comment: string '/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin' (length=29)

Comment: So this is my problem how can modify the env PATH in apache ?

Comment: It is because your Apache is running as root. I have edited my answer showing how to modify the Apache env on Mac.