# The executable "git" is not in the path

Tags: git, review-board

I have Review Board set up on linux RH6.
While i try to "Add Repository" (a git repository) in the administrator dashboard, i get the following error -

> "The executable "git" is not in the path."

on the server, the root account has the git path in the PATH EV.
What else should i check for?

Git version on the server on which Review Board is installed is 1.7.10.2

Comment: I don't know, by Git path, you mean Git repo or Git executable? you need the latter one. Otherwise, no idea. You can search the error in ReviewBoard doc, maybe they use it for something else as well.

Comment: i think it should be the executable. Apache is running on the default 'apache' user. Is it that this user is unable to obtain the path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the path to your git executable to the apache user's PATH.

This might work.

Comment: how to update PATH to apache : add "PATH=$PATH:<path to git>" in the /etc/sysconfig/httpd in Red Hat. Other OS can check -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2837697/how-do-i-add-paths-to-the-apache-path-variable