# ORACLE_HOME is not visible in phpInfo page

Tags: php, oracle, apache, oracle-call-interface, php-ini

In my CentOS machine I have set my `ORACLE_HOME` environment variable in the `~/.bash_profile` file.

My `.bash_profile` file

```
# .bash_profile

# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
        . ~/.bashrc
fi

# User specific environment and startup programs

#PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin
ORACLE_HOME=/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64
PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib
TNS_ADMIN=$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin
export ORACLE_HOME
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export TNS_ADMIN
export PATH
```

`phpInfo()` output:
[image]

How do I set ORACLE_HOME & TNS_ADMIN in the Environment section? Am I doing anything wrong here?

Comment: is phpinfo() executed by your webserver `httpd`? Then you must add PATH to that user. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2837697/how-do-i-add-paths-to-the-apache-path-variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding `export ORACLE_HOME=/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64` to `/etc/sysconfig/httpd` solved the issue.