# How do I add paths to the Apache PATH variable on Windows?

Tags: windows, apache, path

Like this question, I'm look for a solution for Windows 7

[How do I add paths to the Apache PATH variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2837697/how-do-i-add-paths-to-the-apache-path-variable?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Something like that, to SET Apache PATH Variable in Windows 7 (Registry?)

```
export PATH="$PATH":/opt/local/lib/mysql5/bin:/this-is-a-test
```

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Go to System Properties
2. Then, go to “Advanced system settings”
3. Under “Advanced” tab, click on “Environment Variables …” button at the bottom
4. Double click PATH and add new path into the “variable value”. Make sure you separate the value with “; “

Kind regards

Comment: Sorry, don't work. I have do so and reboot the PC, but the Windows PATH is farther different to apache PATH in phpinfo();

Comment: You are right, but I have to login as administrator, because the apache service will use the PATH from admin account! Now it works again!